# R Corrplot Text Spacing

Tags: r, matrix, text, r-corrplot

Is there any way to remove the spaces between dashes? For example, removing the white space between "IL - 1alpha"? I'm not sure if there's any argument I could add in order to do this. Thanks in advance!

Here is a random dataset I created along with the code I use:

```
dat <- data.frame("Eotaxin" = sample(100, size = 66, replace = TRUE), "GRO-alpha" = sample(100, size = 66, replace = TRUE),
                  "IL-1alpha" = sample(100, size = 66, replace = TRUE), "IL-ra" = sample(100, size = 66, replace = TRUE),
                  "IL-8" = sample(100, size = 66, replace = TRUE), "IP-10" = sample(100, size = 66, replace = TRUE),
                  "MIP-1beta" = sample(100, size = 66, replace = TRUE), 
                  "SDF-1alpha" = sample(100, size = 66, replace = TRUE))
library('corrplot')
matrix_cor <- cor(dat)
colnames(matrix_cor) <- c("Eotaxin", 
                          ":GRO*alpha", 
                                     ":IL-1*alpha", 
                                     "IL-ra", 
                                     "IL-8", 
                                     "IP-10", 
                                     ":MIP-1*beta", 
                                     ":SDF-1*alpha")
rownames(matrix_cor) <- c("Eotaxin", 
                          ":GRO*alpha", 
                          ":IL-1*alpha", 
                          "IL-ra", 
                          "IL-8", 
                          "IP-10", 
                          ":MIP-1*beta", 
                          ":SDF-1*alpha")
corrplot(matrix_cor, type = "upper",tl.col="black", tl.cex = 1)
```

[image: corrplot]

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example

Comment: it's using `?plotmath` and interpreting your strings as SDF minus 1 times alpha, use quotes `":'MIP-1'*beta"`